# How to add 3rd party JAR's to compile time classpath in jGRASP?

Tags: java, import

What do I need to do to successfully the import `ij` package? I get an error:

```
ITCN_.java:1: package ij does not exist
```

The imports are:

```
import ij.*; 
import ij.io.*;
import ij.gui.*; 
import ij.process.*; 
import ij.measure.*; 
import ij.plugin.*; 
import ij.plugin.frame.*; 
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter;

import java.io.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.text.*;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [ImageJ API](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/). The API docs are available [here](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html). You can download it [here](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/download.html). Once downloaded, just add the JAR(s) to the compiletime and runtime classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I already downloaded. I guess my questions is really how to add the jar files to the compiletime then. (im using jGRASP)

Comment: I've never heard of it, so I can't go in detail. If you were using Eclipse, all you need to do is to just drop the JAR in the project folder, rightclick it and choose *Build Path > Add to Build Path*. You may consider to reformulate the question or ask a new question which boils down to "How to add 3rd party JAR's to compile time classpath in jGRASP?".

Answer (score 6):

I also used Jgrasp back in the day.

I highly recommend moving to eclipse although jGrasp is very simple and works.

To Add to the Build Path you go to Settings -> PATH/CLASSPATH -> Workspace

Click on the "Path" tab, and then the "CLASSPATHS" subtab.

Then Click "New" and where it says Path or Jar file, enter in the path to the ij jar file. Do this for each file if there are more than one.

And then click "apply" and you should be able to use import ij.* and the subsequent functions