# RectangleTest.java:1: error: package com does not exist

Tags: java, import, package, classpath, subdirectory

For my college course I create a class Rectangle with attributes length and width, each of which defaults to 1. Provide methods that calculate the rectangle's perimeter and area. It has set and get methods for both length and width. The set methods should verify that length and width are each floating points numbers larger than 0.0 and less than 20.0. Write a program that test class Rectangle. Just when I thought I was on a roll learning java I run into this problem that throws me completely off. I am stumped and lost. The class path is set in the environmental variable in the control panel. I did that already. I don't understand about the directory and sub directories bit. I downloaded JUNIT and put it in the same directory as the java projects in this problem. Rectangle.java compiles but RectangleTest.java does not. I get the infamous error "package com does not exist." I'm basically lost. Can anybody shed some light on this problem for me. Here are both applications:

```
 package com.schweidel;
 public class Rectangle
 {
 private double length;//1 - 12
 private double width;//1 - 9
 private double perimeter;//1 - 217
 private double area;//1 - 108

 public void setPerimeter(double l, double w, double p, double a)//declaring and  inititalizing perimeter method
{
    length =((l > 0.00 && l < 20.00)? l: 1);
    width =((w > 0.00 && w < 20.00)? w: 1);
    perimeter =((p> 2.0*(length * width) && p < 217.00)? p: 1);
    area = ((a> length * width && a < 108.00)? a: 1);   
} //end method perimeter

public String toString()//defining toString method
```

{
    return String.format("The measurements are: %.2f: %.2f: %.2f:                    %.2f",length,width,perimeter,area);
   }
   }//end class Rectangle

```
 Here is the test application, that does not compile.

 import com.schweidel;//import com.schweidel
 public class RectangleTest
 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();//calls Rectangle constructor


 System.out.println(rect.toString());
 }//end method main
 }//end class RectangleTest
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies here:

```
import com.schweidel;
```

You are trying to import a package (`com.schweidel`), when one can only import classes. You are getting this error message because the compiler thinks you want to import a class called `schweidel` from a package called `com`.

Most likely, you meant to add the class `RectangleTest` to the package `com.schweidel` by writing:

```
package com.schweidel;
```

If you really intended to import classes from `com.schweidel`, you could write `import com.schweidel.*;` to import all classes, or `import com.schweidel.(class name);` to import a specific class.

Comment: I tried both approaches but I still get the error that 'package com.schweidel does not exist.'

Comment: Are you trying to import a class from `com.schweidel` or are you trying to add `RectangleTest` to the package `com.scweidel`? In the latter case, you should use the `package` keyword instead of `import`.

Comment: import com.schweidel.Rectangle;import com.schweidel.*; This is what I put for the import statement. Still I get the error that com.schweidel does not exist. Is there another solution to this problem? I'm in the text book Java Late Objects Version, Dietel and still can't quite figure out the problem.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Maybe you made `RectangleTest` in a different Java project.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jGRASP, but I think the answer you're looking for might be [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599618/how-to-add-3rd-party-jars-to-compile-time-classpath-in-jgrasp/16321389#16321389) or [here](http://orbiter-forum.com/showthread.php?t=4237).