# How to open and view code from package in Java

Tags: java, package

I'm new to Java, I have a code where there's a package in it. My problem is that I'm trying to run the code on Jgrasp, it's my school program to run code. Jgrasp doesn't use packages. I can't run it because of the package. I don't know how packages work but I wrote an entire code for this and gave it to a friend, he edited my code and made it into a package and says that it works. I don't want the package, I want the fully written code he wrote instead with the main method below.

```
package insta2;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class BottomUpApp {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      BottomUp bup;
      Tree theTree = null;
      int value;
      String str;

      while (true) {
       System.out.print(" Enter first letter of balanced");
       System.out.print(" unbalanced , show , or traverse : ");
       int choice = getChar();
       switch (choice) {
        case 'b':
         System.out.print(" Enter string : ");
         str = getString();
         bup = new BottomUp(str);
         bup.balanced();
         theTree = bup.getTree();
         break;

                   case 'u':
                   System.out.print("Enter string: ");
                   str = getString();
                   bup = new BottomUp(str);
                  bup.unbalanced();
                   theTree = bup.getTree();
                   break;


        case 's':
         theTree.displayTree();
         break;
        case 't':
         System.out.print(" Enter type 1, 2 or 3 : ");
         value = getInt();
         theTree.traverse(value);
         break;
        default:
         System.out.print(" Invalid entry \n ");
       }
      }
     }
     public static String getString() throws IOException {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String s = br.readLine();
      return s;
     }
     public static char getChar() throws IOException {
      String s = getString();
      return s.charAt(0);
     }

     public static int getInt() throws IOException {
      String s = getString();
      return Integer.parseInt(s);
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this question makes no sense.  I see your package and two from Java in the code you posted.  What do you want to see and why?

Comment: I want to see package insta2 code. I'm guessing the package has a written code for it?

Comment: That's why you confuse me.  "package insta2" is at the top of the code you posted.  The class that you posted is in that package.  You have the code.  Are you suggesting that there's more?  Did you write this or did someone else?  If it's the latter, do the same thing you did to post your question.  I'll ask again: What's your real problem?  If you only have a JAR with compiled byte code you can always look at the decompiled source with a smart IDE like IntelliJ.  What's your real problem?

Comment: My problem is that I'm trying to run the code on Jgrasp, it's my school program to run code. I can't run it because of the package. I don't know how packages work but I wrote an entire code for this and gave it to a friend, he made it into a package and says that it works. I don't want the package, I want the fully written code instead with the main method.

Comment: What do you mean you can't run it because of the package?  Do you mean that you have to add a JAR to your CLASSPATH?  You need to learn how to do that, not include source code in your main.

Comment: Where do BottomUp and Tree classes come from?  There's no import for those.  Are they in the 3rd party insta2 package?   Here's a flash: Your drive class should not be in the insta2 package.  You ought to create your own package and import the classes you need from others.  Who's teaching you Java?

Comment: Just delete the line "package insta2;". Jgrasp doesn't understand packages . Have a look at http://www.java-made-easy.com/jgrasp.html   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599618/how-to-add-3rd-party-jars-to-compile-time-classpath-in-jgrasp

Comment: Why bother with such an IDE?  Who is teaching this class?  You'd be better off with a text editor if you'd learn it properly.

Answer (score 0):

jGRASP doesn't have any problem with packages.

I'm guessing your code is not in a directory named "insta2".